# Which authorization system suitable for my scenario?

Tags: .net, authentication, oauth-2.0, openid, saml-2.0

**Information**

I have one small web application which provides an insurance policy for the different electronic devices.Now, I want to integrate this web application with other clients like different telecom web application.

To do this, I have to integrate my small web apps with their web application.
but, I am facing below authorization issue.

**Require Authorization mechanism**

I don't want the user to register with my web app instead of this I want to authorize the user by client side with valid credential details.Notice that i have multiple clients with cross domain platform

I did some research and found that I have to use some authorization protocol to overcome from this situation like saml, OAuth 2.0, OpenID.

So overall, I have to develop one middleware which can authorize user with client side application and then after user can access my service.

- Which protocol is easy to implement with .net technology?
- What type of middleware I need to develop which can communicate with cross 
  origin platform application?
- Which types of configuration client needs to apply to authenticate user that 
  comes from my side

Hoping for best answers...

Answer (score 0):

On the enterprise side, you can use SAML or OIDC.

These enterprises have to have a protocol server stack.

On the client side, you can use both but if you have any native devices (non browser) then OIDC is the way to go.

In terms of middleware, look at the OWIN NuGet packages.

If you want .NET client side, there is no Microsoft SAML stack for this. Refer [SAML : SAML connectivity / toolkit](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2013/06/saml-saml-connectivity-toolkit.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. something in deep ...i want to authenticate the user from the link is it possible?

Comment: Sorry - don't understand. What's the use case?